# How do I copy bytes to/from SharedMemory into BytesIO?

Tags: python, shared-memory, bytesio

I am creating a [`SharedMemory` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html#multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory), where data is being written to it in an I/O bound process for subsequent processing by a separate compute-bound process. In subsequent processing of the data I want to be able to read and write with a file-like object, so I'd like to copy to a `io.BytesIO` object. I'm not sure how to use the `buf` memory view object of the SharedMemory.

How can I copy data between a SharedMemory object and a BytesIO object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the following example setup:

```
from io import BytesIO
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory

b = BytesIO()
s = SharedMemory(create=True, size=1024)
```

you can write the contents of the memory view to the bytes I/O object directly with

```
>>> b.write(s.buf)
1024                # N.B. bytes written equals size of shared memory
```

This works for any file-like object, not just `BytesIO`.

---

To do the reverse, you can extract the contents of the ByteIO object into a [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) string, and then write those bytes to a desired spot in the shared memory by indexing the [`memoryview`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#memoryview) object:

```
b.seek(0)            # change stream position to start
contents = b.read()  # read contents into bytes object

start_idx = 123      # example location
s.buf[start_idx : start_idx + len(contents)] = contents
```

Comment: And what about the reverse process please - writing from the BytesIO into the SharedMemory memoryview?

Comment: @John It's an ordinary memoryview, so you can index it to read/write bytes. You can get a `bytes` object from by ByteIO seeking to the start and reading. See my edit